# copy 2d vector without first row and column

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, copy, stdvector

Just like in topic. I would like to copy one vector to another without first row and column.

'''

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2(v1.size()-1,std::vector<int>(v1.size()-1));

std::copy((v1.begin()+1)->begin()+1,v1.end()->end(),v2.begin()->begin());

return v2;
```

'''

Comment: I believe there is no way of doing this with std::copy, you need to write your own function with a for loop to skip the first element in each row.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a web site where everyone shares what they would like to do, but only specific programming-related questions. What is your question?

Comment: Why don't you just construct the second vector from an iterator pair from the first, that excludes the first entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C++ and views it is easy to drop items while enumerating.
So you can avoid using raw or iterator loops.
Live demo here : https://godbolt.org/z/8xz91Y8cK

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

auto reduce_copy(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> values)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> retval{};

    // drop first row
    for (const auto& row : values | std::views::drop(1))
    {
        // add a new row to retval
        auto& new_row = retval.emplace_back();

        // drop first column
        for (const auto& col : row | std::views::drop(1))
        {
            new_row.emplace_back(col);
        }
    }

    return retval;
}


int main()
{

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
    auto result = reduce_copy(values);

    for (const auto& row : result)
    {
        for (const auto& value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example the ordinary for loop

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

for ( auto first = std::next( std::begin( v1 ) ), target = std::begin( v2 ); 
      first != std::end( v1 ); 
      ++first, ++target )
{
    std::copy( std::next( std::begin( *first ) ), std::end( *first ), std::begin( *target ) );
}
```